# Altering parent variable through child class function in Python

Tags: python, oop

so I just recently started doing OOP in python and I do not have a lot of knowledge in OOP in general. I was wondering if I am able to create Child classes through a parent class and then alter the Parent class variable through the Child class created?

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3

    def create_child(self, count):
        array = []
        for x in range(count):
            array.append(Child(var4=self.var1))
        return array

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, var4):
        super(Parent, self).__init__()
        self.var4 = var4

    def alter_parent_variable(self, value):
        self.var1 += value
```

Say I've created a code as seen above I keep getting an error saying:

TypeError: **init**() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'var1', 'var2', and 'var3'

By using this code to test:

```
test = Parent(20, 50, 1)

array = test.create_child(3)

for x in array:
    x.alter_parent_variable(50)
```

And lets say I added another function with the exact same code as seen in the Parent class into the Child class (As listed below). Am I able to directly alter the Parent class variable through the Child class created by the Child class?

```
    def create_child(self, count):
    array = []
    for x in range(count):
        array.append(Child(var4=self.var1))
    return array
```

Comment: you are calling `super().__init__()` without arguments

Comment: If I were to call `super().__init__()` , what arguments would I put into as arguments if I were to achieve my original aim? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The arguments same as parent class you need to pass 4 arguments

Answer (score 0):

You're getting `TypeError` because you're calling `Parent`'s `__init__` (when you call `super(Parent, self).__init__()`) without giving enough args.

The way you are modifying `Parent`'s `var1` won't work, because while `Child` inherits from `Parent`, they won't be the same class *instance* (`self` always refers to the class *instance*, not the class itself).

But, you can pass a reference to `Parent` itself by passing `self`, and modify `var1` that way.

For example:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, var4, parent: Parent):
        self.var4 = var4
        self.parent = parent

    def alter_parent_variable(self, value):
        self.parent.var1 += value
```

That said, depending on what you're ultimately trying to achieve, there may be better ways of doing things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a good practice to go for apart from the one you just mentioned? I'm not familiar with good OOP coding practices.

Comment: That's a much broader question ;) But passing a reference to the parent via `self` is reasonably common.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll hopefully be able to come over the other methods you mentioned!

Comment: Hi sorry one last question, when I tested the code, the following error was shown.
`AttributeError: type object 'Parent' has no attribute 'var1'`
Is it because I'm not referencing the Parent correcly?

I also modified this line in the Parent class
`array.append(Child(var4=self.var1, parent=Parent))`

Comment: `parent=self` instead of `parent=Parent`. `Parent` is the class, `self` is the class _instance_.